# Fish error while trying to run command on mac

Tags: shell, cmd, fish

I use the following command and I have fish installed

```
diff -y <(unzip -l old.zip) <(unzip -l new.zip)
```

and I get the following error :

```
fish: Invalid redirection target: (unzip -l new.zip)
diff -y <(unzip -l new.zip) <(unzip -l old.zip)
        ^
fish: Invalid redirection target: (unzip -l old.zip)
diff -y <(unzip -l new.zip) <(unzip -l old.zip)
```

is there a workaround?

Comment: Use bash instead.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams - how can I do it on mac ?I've installed git bash and in the `spotlight search` I dont find it

Comment: bash comes with OS X.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams - ive installed fish, is there a way to open the bash without the fish ? can you please say how ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `<(a_command)` syntax is a bash'ism not supported by fish. In keeping with the fish preference for explicit commands rather than magic syntax the `psub` command is used to achieve a similar effect:

```
diff -y (unzip -l new.zip | psub) (unzip -l old.zip | psub)
```

Comment: I would say, the "magic syntax" seems to be very useful here: not only is much shorter command, but it visually helps to see what's the meaning of the command!! I would keep both ways to be honest, "special operator" and "explicit command". Anyway many thanks for your answer, it helped me today.